# R: Generate dataset for pre-defined interaction effects

Tags: r, random

I have generated a random `df` with the continuous variables `V1`, `V2`, and `V3`:

```
set.seed(123)
sigma <- rbind(c(1,-0.4,-0.6), c(-0.4,1,0.5), c(-0.6,0.5,1))
mu <- c(5, 3, 2)
df <- as.data.frame(MASS::mvrnorm(n=1000, mu=mu, Sigma=sigma))
```

Now, I would like to generate an interaction effect between two variables in predicting another one. For example, there should be an interaction between `V1` and `V2` in predicting `V3`. Is there a way to adjust the data in a way to get a pre-defined interaction term estimate of `V1:V2` when computing `summary(lm(V3 ~ V1*V2, data=df))`?

```
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  3.419951   0.376848   9.075  < 2e-16 ***
V1          -0.472042   0.069703  -6.772 2.16e-11 ***
V2           0.328102   0.112497   2.917  0.00362 ** 
V1:V2       -0.003878   0.021811  -0.178  0.85892
```

*Note: I want to use the generated df for a tutorial*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linear regression model, so just just a linear equation with the coefficients you want and a small amount of noise:

```r
set.seed(123)
sigma <- rbind(c(1,-0.4,-0.6), c(-0.4,1,0.5), c(-0.6,0.5,1))
mu <- c(5, 3, 2)
df <- as.data.frame(MASS::mvrnorm(n=10000, mu=mu, Sigma=sigma))
df$V4 <- 1 * df$V1 - 2 * df$V2 + pi * df$V1 * df$V2 + rnorm(nrow(df))

mod <- lm(V4 ~ V1 * V2, df)
summary(mod)
# 
# Call:
# lm(formula = V4 ~ V1 * V2, data = df)
# 
# Residuals:
#     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -4.1343 -0.6755  0.0073  0.6741  3.9650 
# 
# Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  0.183117   0.160119   1.144    0.253    
# V1           0.953835   0.029612  32.211   <2e-16 ***
# V2          -2.041455   0.047475 -43.000   <2e-16 ***
# V1:V2        3.153014   0.009226 341.749   <2e-16 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.999 on 9996 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.9949,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.9949 
# F-statistic: 6.515e+05 on 3 and 9996 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Vincent! Is there another way to adjust V1 and V2 to predict V3, instead of creating a new outcome variable (V4)?

Comment: In my example, you could obviously just generate a 2 column dataset with `mvrnorm` first, because we don't use V3. That way you don't have a superfluous variable.

Comment: That's not what I meant. Your code creates a new outcome variable based on V1 and V2, instead of adjusting V1 and V2 to interact in predicting V3. In other words: I don't want to create a new outcome variable, I would like to adjust the predictor variables based on my outcome variable.

Comment: Got it. I realize that this is not exactly what you wanted, but I'm kind of curious why you need a different approach, given the stated goal. In any case, good luck. Hope you get other answers.